# Select in sql statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can anyone assist me with this below?

I have 10 records in a table with same acc no and different branches. If I fired the query it should not return any values while `where` condition is matched.

For example:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM temp 
 WHERE branch != "xxx"
```

It should not return other 9 records also.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: So, what's the problem ?

Comment: Please show us some **sample data** and the expected and current output of your query

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Using group by statement.

`Select * from temp where Branch !=  "xxx" group by acc no`

Or you can your `top 1` so the query will show only 1 record

`Select top 1 * from temp where branch != "xxx"`

Answer (score -1):

**Use this**

```
Select * from temp 
Where branch != 'xxx'
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)